# Elixir ETS key pattern matching

Tags: elixir, ets

I am using ETS to cached a database schema from postegress using ecto
here are those examples:

> table = :ets.new(:cache_name,[:set, :protected])

and include those registry:

> :ets.insert(table,{:first_table,{1}})
>
> :ets.insert(table,{:first_table,{5}})
>
> :ets.insert(table,{:second_table,{1}})

but the second one replace the first one, for that reason i concat the table name and the id to get a unique key `:ets.insert(table,{:first_table1,{1}})` for these registry, but at the moment that i want the first registry for the first table i have a problem because i contain the same key for the second and it retreive two registry:

> :ets.match_object(table,{:"_",{1}})

how can i specify to ETS that if the key contains the table_name retreive these registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can match part of the atom's name with `:ets.match_object`. I'd suggest using a tuple of table name and id as the key if you want a lookup based on both table and id as well as only table:

```
table = :ets.new(:cache_name, [:set, :protected])

:ets.insert(table, {{:first_table, 1}, {1}})
:ets.insert(table, {{:first_table, 2}, {5}})
:ets.insert(table, {{:second_table, 1}, {1}})

# Get table = :first_table, id = 1
IO.inspect :ets.lookup(table, {:first_table, 1})
# Get table = :first_table and any id
IO.inspect :ets.match_object(table, {{:first_table, :_}, :_})
```

Output:

```
[{{:first_table, 1}, {1}}]
[{{:first_table, 1}, {1}}, {{:first_table, 2}, {5}}]
```